# Unity3d Dynamic FOV script causes error: "std::abs(det) > FLT_MIN"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The only thing I know about the error is what the user CrimsonFreak told me in a similar question: "The literal meaning of the error is that the absolute value of whatever det is, isn't superior as whatever FLT_MIN is in the unity system code." (tysm btw, much apprecieated <3). The error seems to appear when the velocity of the player changes too quickly, for example when crashing into another object at high enough speeds. I solved it temporarily by changing the bounciness of the Physics Material to 0, but now the error is back and I managed to single out that the error is caused by my dynamic FOV, here's that code:

```
void Update()
{
    if (playerPosition == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView = newFieldOfView();
    }
}

private float newFieldOfView()
{
    float speed = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z + 6;
    float targetFOV = (float)Math.Log(speed, 1.1) + 34;

    return (Mathf.Lerp(GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, targetFOV, (float)0.1));
}
```

So my question is: why exactly does this confuse the engine?  I tried changing it to a FixedUpdate() function, but that didn't change anything. Also, any solutions/suggestions of other ways to make a simple dynamic FOV would of course be much appreciated. Thanks to everyone in advance for any and all help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot replicate your problem exactly, but I suspect that the issue may be with the logarithm function, as Log(0)=NaN, which can cause problems. A negative velocity should be a problem too...
I suggest clamping the new FOV value to a feasible range.

```
private float newFieldOfView()
{
    float speed = player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.z + 6;
    speed = Mathf.Abs(speed);
    float targetFOV = (float)Math.Log(speed, 1.1) + 34;
    targetFOV = Mathf.Clamp(targetFOV, 1, 180);

    return (Mathf.Lerp(GetComponent<Camera>().fieldOfView, targetFOV, (float)0.1));
}
```

Comment: Yes of course! Thank you so much for all that effort, it seems like the error only appears when hitting something at an angle, or more specifially with velocity in two vectors, which perhaps is why you weren't able to replicate it. Your solution works great though, thank you so much, and perhaps I should go back to maths class...